# Add react component call inside component on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  }
  }

  handleAddNew() {
    const name = prompt('What language do you want to add?')
  }

  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Please vote</h1>
        <Panel name='Python' />
        <Panel name='JavaScript' />
        <Panel name='PHP' />
        <Panel name='C#' />
                             <=============
        <button className='addNewButton' onClick={() => this.handleAddNew()}><h3>Add new</h3></button>
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

I would like to add another call to the Panel component with the name variable in the handleAddNew function in the place that I have pointed to underneath the other Panel components.

Essentially when the button is clicked a prompt shows asking for the name of the desired language to be added and then creates a new component instance of Panel at the place of the arrow:

```
<Panel name={NAME_FROM_PORMPT} />     <=============
```

I assume this will use state and store the current votes for each panel which is stored in each Panel's state:

```
class Panel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { voteCount: 0 }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({voteCount: this.state.voteCount + 1})
  }

  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div className='panel'>
        <span>
          <h3>{this.state.voteCount}</h3>
        </span>
        <span>
          <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        </span>
        <span>
          <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}><h3>VOTE</h3></button>
        </span>
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and feel free to ask questions so that you are more able to help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I added most of the code for context but my apologies if it is too complicated

Comment: Why not make the method `handleAddNew` a class variable that holds an arrow function? This way the browser doesn't have to create a new function on each render cycle and no bloated code is needed on the `onClick` param value. Arrow functions are transparent and have access to `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you maintain the list panels and render them using `map` will simplify.
On adding new panel from prompt, Just update the state (panels list).

Try some thing like below.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { panels: ['Python', 'Javascript', 'PHP', 'C#'] }
  }

  handleAddNew() {
    const name = prompt('What language do you want to add?')
    this.setState({ panels: [...this.state.panels, name] })
  }

  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Please vote</h1>
        {this.state.panels.map(pan =>  <Panel key={pan} name={pan} />)}
        <button className='addNewButton' onClick={() => this.handleAddNew()}><h3>Add new</h3></button>
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd do: `this.setState({panels: [...this.state.panels, name]})`, saves 2 lines and extra code execution.

Comment: This would work but I also need to store how many votes each language has.

Comment: @FinHARRIS, You can change the `panels` state as Array of objects `[{ name: 'C', votes: 0 }]`.

Comment: Yep that works. Just thought of it as I saw your message, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like this:

```js
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { langs: ["Python", "JavaScript", "PHP", "C#"] };
  }

  handleAddNew() {
    const name = prompt("What language do you want to add?");
    this.setState({ langs: [...this.state.langs, name] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Please vote</h1>
        {this.state.langs.map((lang) => (
          <Panel name={lang} />
        ))}
        <button className="addNewButton" onClick={() => this.handleAddNew()}>
          <h3>Add new</h3>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```